# Mysqli/PHP log-in code fault

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

**EDIT:** Turns out I misused the `mysqli_connect` syntax. Thanks everyone.

First off, big noob in mysql and databases, but master the basics of PHP.

That said, I'm working on a log-in script that lets you log in using a linked database. I googled 'php log-in script' and got a small tutorial. Below you can see the code from that website (converted, by me, to mysqli):

```
$mysql_host = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "my_database";
$mysql_password = "my_password";
$mysql_database = "my_database";
$mysql_table = "my_table";

// Connect to server and select database.
$con=mysqli_connect("$mysql_host", "$mysql_user", "$mysql_password")or die("Can't connect!")

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $mysql_table WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysqli_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

    // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
    session_register("myusername");
    session_register("mypassword"); 
    header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
```

I put the code you can read above in a separate PHP document which is linked to by a simple form. I do understand all of the code, but I can't find out why it won't work. I've checked the query in phpMyAdmin and it gets the table and it's contents. When I try to log in with 'john' and the matching password, it gives me a blank screen, which means a php error. I do not have access to the server hosting the website, so cannot get to the errors.

Is there a fault in my code or is it something else?

Thank you.

Comment: First of all you should pass the database name to `mysqli_connect()` and you should also give the connection as the first parameter of the query `mysqli_query($con, $sql);`

Comment: The problem is that mysqli_query accepts a different count of parameters than mysql_query. The same issue to mysqli_connect and mysql_connect

Comment: also remove quotes from params you're passing to mysqli_connect

Comment: Being master in basics you should have been learned to consult a function's manual page before use

Comment: It seems you know the proper syntax already but for some reason decided to refrain from following it. Either way you have got your answer already

Comment: Is it accepted within this community if I alter my question so that it will cover a new problem I encountered with the same code? Or do I need to make a new question for that? Before this problem, I also encountered that problem, and also couldn't solve it.

Comment: Neither. Just don't try to "learn" by means of posting random nonsense code and then asking someone to write you a new one. Get yourself a tutorial instead and run every single example from it

Comment: I was seriously baffled about this one. I searched for solutions for over an hour and couldn't solve it. It didn't occur to me to look at the code syntax, which I should have. Sorry for trying to "learn" php/mysql and asking fellow programmers for help. I'll just wait for this question to get closed.

Comment: Ok, I get it. No need to treat me like the way you just did.

Answer (score -1):

You have error in connection and query part.

In connection part, also provide db like;

```
$con = mysqli_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password, $my_database) or die("Can't         connect!")
```

In query part, you should provide connection also like;

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

You can refere [mysqli_connect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) and [mysqli_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) for more detail